# Perform a predetermined set of operations on a large sequence

Tags: python, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded

This is a programming challenge.

I have been given the following input:

> 1. \$n\$ where n is size of sequence
> 2. \$k\$ is an integer
> 3. a sequence \$A_0, A_1, A_2, \ldots A_{n-1}\$

I need to perform for each index from 0 to (k-1) inclusive

> ```
> find a,b
> where a = A[i % n] and b = A[n - (i % n) - 1]
> then set A[i % n] = a XOR b
> ```

and output the final sequence, separated by spaces

The inputs are within the ranges:

> \$n \leq 10^4\$
>   \$k \leq 10^{12}\$
>   \$A_i \leq 10^7\$

I have applied the following naive approach

```
n,k=map(int,input().split())   
arr=list(map(int,input().split())) #read input sequence and store it as list type
for i in range(k): #iterate over 0 to (k-1)
    t=i%n          #module of i wrt n
    arr[t]=arr[t]^arr[n-(t)-1]  #xor between two list elements and then set result to the ith list element 
for i in arr:
    print(i,end=" ")  #print the final sequence
```

This code runs in 2 seconds when \$K \leq 10^6\$, but it shows Time Limit exceeded for large test cases.
I am looking for an alternate suggestion for the problem

Comment: From which site comes this problem? Are you interested in alternative implementations or a review of the code provided? Please take a look at the [help/on-topic] before answering the latter and modify your question accordingly.

Comment: Link to problem : https://www.codechef.com/OCT19B/problems/MARM

Comment: I am looking for an alternative approach as i know my naive approach wouldn't work for large values of K

Comment: @Mast _Not looking for the review of my code_ is against the very purpose of this site: Code Review :)

Comment: For a next question, I give you this link (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). I hope we can avoid ping-ponging your next question between sites :)

Comment: Why are you modulating `A[i % n]`? The modulus has no effect because `A` is of length `n`.

Comment: @Reinderien The modulo is required because the problem has the index `i` going from `0` to `k-1`, where `k` can be 100 million times larger than `n`.  The OP’s solution works because it has the modulo operation.  It just Time-Limit-Exceeded because it is inefficient.

Comment: Please note that editing the question after an answer is available might invalidate that answer. This is why your edits are being rolled back. You are free to post a self-answer or a follow-up question with updated code instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Now that that pesky "*Not looking for the review of my code*" is gone...

### Step 1: White space

Follow the [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) guidelines, specifically (but not limited to) put a space around operators and after commas:

```
n, k = map(int, input().split())   
arr = list(map(int, input().split()))   # read input sequence and store it as list type
for i in range(k):                      # iterate over 0 to (k-1)
    t = i % n                           # module of i wrt n
    arr[t] = arr[t] ^ arr[n - (t) - 1]  # xor between two list elements and then set result to the ith list element 
for i in arr:
    print(i, end=" ")                   # print the final sequence
```

Much easier to read.

### Step 2: Avoid multiple lookups

Python is an interpreted language, and the meaning of a line of code -- or even a fragment of code -- can change by the time the interpreter returns to execute the code as second time.  This means the interpreter cannot truly compile the code; unless something is a well defined short-circuiting operation, every operation must be executed.

Consider:

```
arr[t] = arr[t] ^ arr[n - (t) - 1]
```

The interpreter must compute the address of `arr[t]` twice; once to fetch the value, and a second time to store the new value, because some side-effect which occurs during the execution of `arr[n - (t) - 1]` may change the meaning of `arr[t]`.  In your case, `arr` is a `list`, and `n` and `t` are simple integers, but with user-defined types, anything can happen.  As such, the Python interpreter can never make the following optimization:

```
arr[t] ^= arr[n - (t) - 1]
```

It is a tiny speed-up, but considering the code may execute \$10^{12}\$ times, it can add up.

### Step 3: Avoid calculations

Speaking of avoiding work: because we know the length of the array is fixed, `arr[n - 1]` is the same as `arr[-1]`.  So we can further speed up the line of code as follows:

```
arr[t] ^= arr[-1 - t]
```

Instead of two subtractions, we now have only one.  Yes, Python has to index from the back of the array, which internally is going to involve a subtraction, **BUT** that will be an optimized, C-coded subtraction operation on `ssize_t` values, instead of subtraction on variable byte length integers, which must be allocated and deallocated from the heap.

### Step 4: Printing space-separated lists

The following is slow:

```
for i in arr:
    print(i, end=" ")
```

This is faster:

```
print(*arr)
```

And for long lists, this may be fastest:

```
print(" ".join(map(str, arr)))
```

For a detail discussion, including timing charts, see [my answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/226970/printing-a-list-as-a-b-c-using-python/226976#226976) and [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/226974/100620) on another question.

### Step 5: The Algorithm

Consider the list `[A, B, C, D, E]`.

After applying a single pass of the operation on it (ie, `k = n`), you'll get:

```
[A^E, B^D, C^C, D^(B^D), E^(A^E)]
```

which simplifies to:

```
[A^E, B^D, 0, B, A]
```

If we apply a second pass (ie, `k = 2*n`), you'll get:

```
[(A^E)^A, (B^D)^B, 0^0, B^((B^D)^B), A^((A^E)^A)]
```

which simplifies to:

```
[E, D, 0, B^D, A^E]
```

A third pass, (ie, `k = 3*n`) gives:

```
[E^(A^E), D^(B^D), 0^0, (B^D)^(D^(B^D)), (A^E)^(E^(A^E))]
```

or:

```
[A, B, 0, D, E]
```

Now `k` does not need to be an exact multiple of `n`, so you'll have to figure out what to do in the general cases, but you should be able to use the above observation to eliminate a lot of unnecessary calculations.

Implementation left to student.

Comment: One of the potential offenders is also the mod operation. It might (or might not) be faster to use an increment with an if after that.

Comment: i have updated my implementation using the above algorithm getting right answer on most of the self-made cases but looks like one of case is not working properly. so Wrong Answer error

Comment: I have rolled back your most recent edit.  You may not edit your question to incorporate suggestions made in answers.  See [what should I do when someone answers my question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) in the help center.

Comment: sorry for the edit in question. I have posted my updated approach as a self -answer

Answer (score 4):

Any solution which does something \$k\$ times will be hopelessly slow. We have to make use of the structure of the problem here. Suppose \$i<\lfloor n/2\rfloor\$ and write \$ a = A_i \$ and \$b= A_{n-i}\$. Then each time through the list we execute \$ a \leftarrow a\wedge b \$ and then \$b\leftarrow a\wedge b\$. Lets record the values of \$a \$ and \$b\$ on each iteration of the loop, starting with values \$x\$ and \$ y\$ for \$a\$ and \$ b\$, respectively:

1. First \$a \leftarrow x\wedge y\$, then \$b \leftarrow (x\wedge y)\wedge y = x\$
2. First \$a \leftarrow (x\wedge y) \wedge x = y\$, then \$b\leftarrow y\wedge x\$
3. First \$a \leftarrow y \wedge (y\wedge x) = x\$, then \$b\leftarrow x \wedge (y\wedge x) = y\$

Notice that the effect of three such iterations is to do nothing at all. Therefore we can subtract any multiple of \$ 3n\$ from \$k\$ and not change the result. If you reduce \$k\$ mod \$3 n\$ before executing your original code, you should be good. (Actually we have to be a little careful to handle the case of odd \$n\$, because the middle element has to be handled specially. I leave this as an exercise).

Comment: updated my implementation as per the algorithm suggested but still getting wrong answer on submission. It works perfectly on my self made test cases though

Answer (score 0):

**

> Re:Updated implementation approach for the problem

**

After combining algorithm suggested my

> @AJNeufeld and @vujazzman

Sequence remains same if loop is run upto any multiple of `(N*3)`

so we can save the overhead of running for all values of `k`

Rather find the closest multiple of `(n*3) to K` and then `run loop for remaining value from the found multiple to k`

Note:- Odd number `n` case to be handled separately in advance by `set A[n//2] = 0`

so i have came up with the following implementation:

```
for _ in range(int(input())):
    n,k=map(int,input().split())
    arr=list(map(int,input().split()))
    if n % 2 and k > n//2 :           #odd n case
        arr[ n//2 ] = 0
    rem= k % ( 3*n )
    closest_multiple_3n = ( k-rem )
    for i in range( closest_multiple_3n,k ):
        t=i % n
        arr[t] ^= arr[-1-t]
    print(*arr)
```

i have created some self made test cases like :-

```
t=1
n=11 k=9999999998
A[] = 20 7 27 36 49 50 67 72 81 92 99

output:- 20 7 27 36 49 0 67 72 81 92 119

note :- closest_multiple_3n = 9999999966
         rem = 32
        (20^92=119)
```

It works perfectly now

Comment: Code review is not intended to be used for collaborative coding to get things working (faster). While this post provides a (hopefully) improved code base, it's not a code review. I am converting it to a wiki answer (instead of deleting it). Please consider analyzing the actual performance of the code, and seeing if there is a different approach you can take. If it were me, I would benchmark your original code, then this code, and then possibly ask a new question if this revised code is faster, but not fast enough.

Comment: okay i have updated my answer and the code in it works well !!